# How to change object values with another object key path?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change the destination values with source object key path?

The source object is like below

```js
{
  "total-info": [{
    "emp-sal-info": {
      "id": "emp01",
      "currency": "dollar",
      "details": {
        "sal-details": [{
            "name": "peter",
            "income": "$400"
          },
          {
            "name": "peter wife",
            "income": "$500"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }, {
    "emp-sal-info": {
      "id": "emp01",
      "currency": "dollar",
      "details": {
        "sal-details": [{
            "name": "John",
            "income": "$900"
          },
          {
            "name": "John wife",
            "income": "$400"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

The destination is like this:

```js
{
  "company": [{
    "Peter": {
      "id": "emp01",
      "sal": "$3000"
    }
  }, {
    "John": {
      "id": "emp02",
      "sal": "$5000"
    }
  }]
}
```

Then how do I change the destination object to the below format?

```js
{
  "company": [{
    "Peter": {
      "id": "emp01",
      "sal": "['total-info']['0']['emp-sal-info']['details']['sal-details']['0']['salary']+['total-info']['0']['emp-sal-info']['details']['sal-details']['0']['salary']"
    }
  }, {
    "John": {
      "id": "emp02",
      "sal": "['total-info']['1']['emp-sal-info']['details']['sal-details']['0']['salary']+['total-info']['1']['emp-sal-info']['details']['sal-details']['0']['salary']"
    }
  }]
}
```

Can you please tell me how transform to arrays like above. Thanks you

Comment: Firstly note that this doesn't have anything to do with JSON. The data structures you have are objects containing arrays. I've edited the question as such. Secondly, SO is here to help you debug code, not to write it for you. Please edit the question to show your attempt and include details of which part of the code you're having issues with. Lastly, the format you're looking to create makes very little sense - even in context of seeing the two previous objects.

Comment: Create an array. Loop through your object with [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) 
, get the data you need and [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the new objects in the format you want to your created array. Then you write the array in an object with the property "company"